# What is the disadvantage of using SHRINK SPACE for an Oracle Table?

Tags: oracle, alter-table

I am going to develop a reporting database by querying the production database once using a stored procedure.

The stored procedure will then write the result into it's own output tables.

Following is the schema for the output table:

```
Create table Output (
    Customer_ID                  NUMBER(15)           not null,
    STD_HASH                     RAW(1000 BYTE)       ,

    VALID_PERIOD_START           NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6),
    VALID_PERIOD_END             NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6),
    Address                      VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),

    period for valid_period(valid_period_start,valid_period_end),

    Constraint Output_PK Primary Key ( Customer_ID, valid_period_start, valid_period_end )
)
```

As the stored procedure will perform a lot of update and delete statement on the output table, and those output table is very big. The largest one I have right now is 8GB. I am thinking to alter those output tables with the "SHRINK SPACE" option at the end of the stored procedure to reclaim some spaces.

Following is the statement that I am going to apply:

```
    Alter table OUTPUT1 ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT; -- Temporary enable row movement for the table
    Alter TABLE output2 SHRINK SPACE;
    Alter table OUTPUT1 DISABLE ROW MOVEMENT;-- Disable row movement.
```

Those output tables are temporal table that is using the valid period and the ID from production as a primary key.

However, as I am very new with the Shrink Space function. Can anyone tell me what is the disadvantage of using this function?

The table, basically will not be updated from anywhere other than this stored procedure. The stored procedure will be scheduled to run in a daily base.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You normally should never need to run `SHRINK SPACE` and you don't need to reclaim space for the DB to reuse in future. The database does that automatically or through automated maintenance actions. What edition and version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I think it is an oracle 12

Comment: I agree that the database should be able to automatically do this. But I just thinking to reclaim it instantly..

Comment: "But I just thinking to reclaim it instantly" - unless you're short on disk space, don't. After records are physically deleted the engine will re-use the space. Never try to outsmart a DB engine as complicated as Oracle.

Comment: Hi Dal, Thanks for your advice. I will look for another alternative to save spaces.

Comment: You're missing my point, though - you _don't need to save space_, really. Unless you're running low on disk-space? Or you're seeing _excessively_ wasted space (e.g. more than 2-3x the amount of data space actually used by rows and indexes?)? In which case _yes_ that's a problem.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. What I was intended to say is, I will try to find some other solution way to build a smaller output table rather than using this option. As I do received complain from my DBA that I used up too much spaces. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Why is your `STD_HASH` value sized at 1000 bytes? Hashes are much shorter, like MD5 is 16 bytes, SHA-25 is 32 bytes. What hash algorithm are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, shrink has some restrictions:
(1) it locks the table during the shrink operation
(2) it change the rowid of the table.
(3) it needs the tablespace with automatic segment-space management enabled.

we have other alternatives to claim the unused space:
(1) export/import
(2) dbms_redefinition